# Issue with RadPane content Freezing After Resetting Layout on Floating State

Tags: wpf, telerik, cefsharp

My application utilizes the RadDocking control to manage layout, including a RadPane that hosts a **CefSharp** browser. I've observed that when this pane is docked and I reset the layout, everything functions as expected - the layout resets and the browser remains responsive. However, if I float the pane (detach it so it becomes a window) and then reset the layout, the browser within the pane freezes and becomes unresponsive.

```
  <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.2*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <telerik:RadDocking x:Name="radDocking" HasDocumentHost="False" SerializationTag="Docking">
            <telerik:RadSplitContainer telerik:RadDocking.SerializationTag="S1">
                <telerik:RadPaneGroup x:Name="RadPaneGroup1" telerik:RadDocking.SerializationTag="G1">
                    <telerik:RadPane x:Name="RadPane1" telerik:RadDocking.SerializationTag="P1">
                        <TextBlock Text="Pane 1"/>
                    </telerik:RadPane>
                </telerik:RadPaneGroup>
            </telerik:RadSplitContainer>
            <telerik:RadSplitContainer telerik:RadDocking.SerializationTag="S2">
                <telerik:RadPaneGroup x:Name="RadPaneGroup2" telerik:RadDocking.SerializationTag="G2">
                    <telerik:RadPane x:Name="RadPane2" telerik:RadDocking.SerializationTag="P2">
                        <wpf:ChromiumWebBrowser Name="Browser" Initialized="Browser_OnInitialized"/>
                    </telerik:RadPane>
                </telerik:RadPaneGroup>
            </telerik:RadSplitContainer>
        </telerik:RadDocking>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Reset Layout" Click="ResetLayout_Click"/>
    </Grid>
```

```
 public partial class MainWindow
 {
     public MainWindow()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
         SaveLayout();
     }
     
     private void Browser_OnInitialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         string videoUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/JrNMyzsYr4M?autoplay=1&mute=1";

         string html = $@"
         <html>
             <head>
                 <meta charset='utf-8'>
             </head>
             <body style='margin:0; padding:0;'>
                 <iframe width='100%' height='100%' src='{videoUrl}' frameborder='0' allow='autoplay; encrypted-media' allowfullscreen></iframe>
             </body>
         </html>
         ";

         Browser.LoadHtml(html, "http://dummy.com");
     }

     private void SaveLayout()
     {
         using (IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForAssembly())
         {
             using (var isoStream = storage.OpenFile("RadDocking_Layout.xml", FileMode.Create))
             {
                 radDocking.SaveLayout(isoStream);
                 isoStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                 StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(isoStream);
                 reader.ReadToEnd();
             }
         }
     }

     private void ResetLayout_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {
         using (IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForAssembly())
         {
             using (var isoStream = storage.OpenFile("RadDocking_Layout.xml", FileMode.Open))
             {
                 radDocking.LoadLayout(isoStream);
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

The primary question I have is: **Why does the browser freeze only when the pane is floating and I reset the layout**, and how can I prevent this without resorting to programmatically docking the pane before the reset?

Comment: Are you generating any console errors doing this? Have you posted this to the Telerik forums? They're pretty responsive and with a well thought out question will usually give a really well thought out answer.

Comment: The browser has likely been `Disposed`. The default behaviour is to `Dispose` the `ChromiumWebBrowser` when the parent window is unloaded. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/d9a89cb0cb6e5288753de06a3adc1dab85f8dc3e/CefSharp.Wpf/ChromiumWebBrowser.cs#L1561 Create your own class that derives from `ChromiumWebBrowser` and override `OnCleanupElementChanged` to control this behaviour.